# last login time for users openldap 2.3

Tags: openldap

currently I am running openldap 2.3.43. Is there anyway I can get the last login time of a user using authtimestamp or any other attribute? I came to know that this is doable through lastbind overlay. But it is available only for 2.4 it seems. Can anyone let me know if I can do this on 2.3 version?

Comment: btw, I am using ldap as a centralised authentication mechanism for linux boxes and I want to see the last time the user made a ldap bind request to authenticate to a linux box.

Comment: You can get it via the audit log, but it ain't easy.